# Debugging surefire/junit's taste in test cases

Tags: junit

Puzzled: I added a new test case function to a junit test. I run the entire class from either Eclipse or from maven, and the old case (there was only one before) runs and the new one does not. It doesn't fail. A breakpoint in it is not hit. The new function has an @Test annotation, just like the old one.

Junit version is 4.5.

Is there a way to get junit to log or trace its thought process in selecting functions to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you still ran old class file, as new Java file was not be compiled successfully.
You could modify an old test method to see if the class is really modified: to let successful method to fail.